# Get value from form with button click? without submit

Tags: php, html, ajax

[image]I have a form with three buttons.. one button is to edit form in another page, second one is to add value on existing page, third one its to delete value.. submit and edit works well.. now i need to work on delete button.. as it is a button.. i am unable to get value with `$_POST` or `$_GET` and `$_REQUEST` i have done something like this..

```
<form method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="example_text" />

  <a href="index.php?del">
    <input type="button" value="Delete" />
  </a>
  <!-- works fine !-->
  <a href="someotherpage.php">
  <input type="button" value="edit" />
    </a>
  <!-- works fine !-->
  <input type="submit" name="submit" />
  </form>

<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
echo "submit can get value by $_POST";
$name = $_POST['example_text'];
}
if(isset($_GET['del']))
{
$name = $_REQUEST['example_text']; // this can't get value;
$name = $_POST['example_text'];  // this can't get value;
$name = $_GET['example_text']; // this can't get value;
}
?>
```

Comment: can i use two submits? in one form?

Comment: Yes you can, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<form method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="example_text" />

  <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" />

  <a href="someotherpage.php">
    <input type="button" name="edit" value="Edit" />
  </a>

  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<?php

    if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
    {
        $name = $_REQUEST['example_text'];
        echo "Submit method: ".$name;
    }

    if(isset($_REQUEST['delete']))
    {
        $name = $_REQUEST['example_text'];
        echo "Delete method: ".$name;
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

replace

```
<a href="index.php?del">
    <input type="button" value="Delete" />
  </a>
```

to

```
<input type="submit" value="Delete" name="del"/>
```

give your each button a name so you can check which button has been submitted

for check delete button clicked

```
if(isset($_POST['del'])) {
}
```

Comment: you can set multiple submit by using name different like name="del"

Answer (score 1):

**Try this it will work fine :**

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function button1()
{
var r=  document.getElementById('example_text').value;

window.location="getdetails.php?data="+r;
}
function button2()
{
var r=  document.getElementById('example_text').value;

window.location="getdetails.php?data="+r;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="example_text" id="example_text"/>

  <a href="index.php?del">
    <input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="button1()"/>
  </a>
  <!-- works fine !-->
  <a href="someotherpage.php">
  <input type="button" value="edit" onclick="button1()"/>
    </a>
  <!-- works fine !-->
  <input type="submit" name="submit" />
  </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: nice share.. but i was looking for php

Answer (score 0):

Typo:

Change

```
$name = $_REQUESR['example_text']; // this can't get value;
```

To:

```
$name = $_REQUEST['example_text']; // this can't get value;
```